# Using xlrd, how to replace missing/NaN cells

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am using python to plot data from excel files. I am having problems with  cells which have missing data and are filled with 'NA'.
I have worked out how to replace them with 0, but can I replace them with blank cells instead? (Currently they mess up my graphs with the data going to 0 all over the place)
Here is my script:

```
import xlrd

book= xlrd.open_workbook('CHATS_tracegases_allLevels.xls')
level_1=book.sheet_by_index(0)

# Level 1 variables
time_1=level_1.col_values(0, start_rowx=10, end_rowx=None)
ozone_1=level_1.col_values(2, start_rowx=10, end_rowx=None)

ozone_1 = [float(i) if i != 'NA' else 0 for i in ozone_1]
plot(time_1, ozone_1)
show()
```

Also any advice on how I can write my script better would be much appreciated (I have 6 sheets, with 8 variables in each sheet which I need to plot. So if I write it all out like the example above, it gets super huge and probably very inefficient)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with xlrd, but does `if i != 'NA' else ''` not work?

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately, as then I get the error "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Comment: When you say blank value , can't you completely ignore them when creating ozone_1 ?

Comment: Problem solved! `ozone_1 = [float(i) if i != 'NA' else 'NaN' for i in ozone_1]`

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it , would be more helpful that way .

Comment: What plotting library are you using?

Comment: I am using matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ozone_1 = [float(i) if i != 'NA' else 'NaN' for i in ozone_1]`